# Forward port from external connection to a computer in LAN (Ubuntu-iptables)

Tags: linux, iptables, rdp

i've a problem, i can't connect from outside my LAN to a windows computer using Remote Desktop.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, iptables.

```
External Inferface: eth1
LAN Intergace: eth2
Windows IP: 192.168.1.100
Serverlinux LAN IP: 192.168.1.2
Serverlinux External IP: 186.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Actual iptables config:

```
iptables-restore <<-EOF
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
COMMIT
EOF
```

i've trying a lot of examples but with not luck.

Example 1:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --sport 3389 -j SNAT --to 192.168.1.2
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Example 2:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp --destination-port 3389 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT 192.168.1.100:3389
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Example 3: Error (iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.)

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d 186.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3386 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:3399 
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth2 -d 192.168.1.100 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3399 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

What are i missing??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following forwards port 1337 of the external IP address to port 3389 on the internal IP address:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 186.xxx.xxx.xxx -p tcp --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:3389
iptables -I FORWARD -o eth2 -d 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```

The first rule (in the nat table, which you missed in your third example) rewrites the destination address of the packet when it comes in.  The second rule permits the newly rewritten packet to be forwarded.

I have removed all references of the incoming interface, as I assume you want it to work even if you are behind the router (just for the sake of consistency)

Comment: Thank, but still not working....

Comment: Do you have more than one public IP on the router?

If so, you should might need a rule SNAT'ing it correctly as well:
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.100 -p tcp --sport 3389 -j SNAT --to-source 186.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 1337 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.100:3389

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.100 --dport 3389 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: This answer lacks some explanation.